# my contextapi is refusing to work and give me a blank page when i am using it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-context, react-state-management

I have been training myself lately on using react context API. now I tried it on a personal project but apparently, my context API doesn't work.

Context.js

```
import { createContext,useState } from "react";
import React from "react";


export const Mycontext = createContext([]);



export function Context({children}) {
    //put all states here
    const [type,setType] = useState(0)
    const [color,setColor] = useState('white')

  return (
    <Mycontext.Provider value={[type,setType,color,setColor]}>
        {children}
    </Mycontext.Provider>
    
  )
}

export default Context
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Context from './Context';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Context>
  <BrowserRouter>
  
  <App />

  </BrowserRouter>
  

  </Context>
  

  
    
  
);
```

now when I call it as :
Const[type,setType]= createContext(Context);
in any component, the whole page goes blank I don't know what I did wrong here

Comment: You have to use `useContext` not `createContext`

Comment: As an addition to the first comment, I would recommend passing an object to Context provider's `value` prop instead of an array so you don't have to worry about the variables order when destructuring these values on any component consuming the context.